# Is it safe to check the mode of an uploaded image in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, image-uploading

I need to test whether an image uploaded in Django has an alpha layer, so I created this validator:

```
def validate_image_has_alpha_channel(image_file):
   if Image.open(image_file).mode not in ('RGBA', 'LA'):
       raise ValidationError('The image must have an alpha layer')
```

However, I recall that Django patched a [security vulnerability](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2012/jul/) to do with the way image dimension were determined and want to ensure that I'm not introducing this problem in another form.

Reading the source-code for PIL, it's not clear to me in all cases how much image data needs to be loaded for the image mode to be determined (it seems to vary depending on the decoder being used).

Is my code OK, or do I need to use a similar technique to the one used to determine the size?